# DialogFlow: handling given-names with multiple segments

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to make a chatbot using DialogFlow to handle our user registration process. Now, I'm having problems with the $sys.given-name entity. It seems like it cannot parse given names with multiple tokens (i.e., Peter Paul, Tommy Lee, etc.).

[image: It can parse "Mary", but if I enter "Peter Paul", it only parses "Peter"]

Comment: It can successfully parse "Mary", but if I enter something like "Peter Paul", it will only parse "Peter" as the given name and ignore "Paul"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dialogflow supports **lists** of entities, and you can use this to solve your problem.

Enter a name in your User Says phrases, e.g. "Tommy Lee". You'll see that this was detected as a first and last name.

[image: Dialogflow UI]

Now, select the "Lee" part that is currently highlighted as `@sys.last-name`. You can then use the UI to recategorize this as `@sys.given name:given-name`. The `:` marks the parameter name, so this is a `@sys.given-name` entity that has the parameter name `given-name`.

[image: Dialogflow UI]

Both of the name parts are now assigned to the parameter name `given-name`. Because of this, the `given-name` parameter is now a list. You can see this in the UI below; the "IS LIST" box is checked.

[image: Dialogflow UI]

Now, you can provide any set of first names and the `given-name` will be a list populated with all of them. If you try this in the console, you'll see that the JSON will contain an array of names under `given-name`.

```
{
  "id": "cd91e7a1-be53-422e-a3f9-cb1feb3f49bb",
  "timestamp": "2018-01-25T00:13:13.948Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Tommy Lee",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "given-name": [
        "Tommy",
        "Lee"
      ]
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "80b4d66b-ae95-43fd-afee-c590f049a123",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "Multiple names"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Your name is Tommy and Lee",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Your name is Tommy and Lee"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "d1053c3e-4009-4556-8560-3b9fd23eefe5"
}
```

The one catch here is that if you use `$given-name` in your response, Dialogflow will treat the item as a list - so for Tommy Lee, "Your name is $given-name" will be interpolated as "Your name is Tommy and Lee". You can get around this by using fulfillment and doing the interpolation yourself in the webhook.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you set @sys.given-name and mark it as list, like you have in your screenshots.  However then the problem becomes that your line at the bottom will output like so:

```
Nice to meet you $given-name
Nice to meet you Tommy and Lee
```

You can avoid this by using the original call to print out the name exactly as it was passed in.  The output will go like this:

```
Nice to meet you $given-name.original
Nice to meet you Tommy Lee
```

Answer (score 0):

`@sys.given-name` entity will be able to recognize only given names like **Mary** from **Mary Gold**, **Peter** from **Peter Paul** etc.

You should try it like `@sys.given-name @sys.last-name`. In the code you can merge them to have the whole name.

Comment: The problem is what if someone has multiple segments for the given name? For example, William Bradley Pitt (William Bradley is the given name, and not just William). My given name, for example, is Irvin Lee. How are we supposed to teach Dialog Flow that given names can have multiple parts?